# find_by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Rails, I can say:

```
Post.find_by_user_id 1
```

But is there any way to say something like

```
Post.find_by_user User.first
```

?

Not a big deal, but would be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flip to:

```
User.first.posts
```

Or, use a "scope" on Posts... so you could:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_user, lambda{|user| where(:user_id => user.id) }
end
```

And you'd use:

```
user = User.first
Post.for_user(user)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
User.first.posts
```